Cognos BI Analytics New Version Updates on Charts
We will soon upgrade our IBM Cognos environment from 10.2.2 to the latest 12.0.3.
One of the things we are looking forward to is more dynamic charts and visuals specifically the speedometer
This is the first image depicting one of the limitations in palette color scheme, we prefer that it would be dynamic coloring based on certain logics enter image description here.
In addition to this axis range that takes hardcoded manual input enter image description here
Thank you!

Is there a question here?  There's a lot wrong with this.  Are you asking how to accomplish something, or are you hoping someone on the IBM Cognos Analytics design team reads this and makes different choices?  Please be clearer.  Also, please use the appropriate tags.  For example, from the ibm-cloud page:  "When asking questions about the IBM Cloud platform, you should:  Ensure you are asking a technical question about using the IBM Cloud platform or services."  You don't appear to be asking anything about IBM Cloud.
